# How to use make's --jobs with subdirs?

Tags: makefile, jobs

Build time of my C++ project is very big. It consists of a bunch of subprojects (libraries), structured in file system folders. I want to speed up it with parallel build with --jobs (-j) parameter of make. What is the correct way of doing it? Documentation says that there are some tricks of doing parallel build with subdirs.

Makefile in root directory looks like:

```
...
all:
    $(MAKE) -C DirA
    $(MAKE) -C DirB
...
```

Makefile in DirA:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C SubDirA
    $(MAKE) -C SubDirB
    $(MAKE) -C SubDirC
```

In DirB:

```
all:
    $(MAKE) -C SubDirD
    $(MAKE) -C SubDirE
    $(MAKE) -C SubDirF
```

And so on. Makefiles in leaf folders are quite simple, contain only build instruction without any tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `-j` to `make` using these makefiles as-is and you'll get some parallelism, but you won't get maximum parallelism.  The problem is that make only parallelizes targets: clearly it won't work (in general) to run multiple commands in the same target in parallel!

So, in the top level make will run `$(MAKE) -C DirA` then `$(MAKE) -C DirB`, serially.  When make builds `DirA`, it will first run `$(MAKE) -C SubDirA`, then `$(MAKE) -C SubDirB`, etc. serially.  Then finally when make gets into `SubDirA`, it will build the targets there in parallel.  This is fine, and maybe what you need to do if the order of building directories is important, except that there will be times when make could start working on `SubDirB` targets but won't, until all targets in `SubDirA` are complete.

A better way to handle subdirectories is to use make rules:

```
SUBDIRS := DirA DirB
all: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@
.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)
```

and ditto for the subdirectories.  Note you *must* include the `.PHONY`.

Since each directory is a separate target, now make can invoke them in parallel if you use `-j`.

Oh, and if some of the contents of some subdirectories depends on others, you can declare that dependency explicitly in the makefile so make know about it:

```
SUBDIRS := SubDirA SubDirB SubDirC SubDirD
all: $(SUBDIRS)
$(SUBDIRS):
        $(MAKE) -C $@
.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

SubDirA: SubDirD
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, I will check it soon. BTW, what if directory names contain whitespaces? For example 'Dir A'. How should I handle it?Mb put in quotes or escape with \\?

Comment: You cannot use paths containing whitespace with make, essentially.

Comment: @QtRoS, if your directory names contain spaces (which I don't recommend, but you might be stuck with), then you can't give the rule the same name as the directory.  So you end up with one rule per subdir, rather than a single pattern rule as above.  If there's a legal character for targets (e.g. `_`) that's never in a directory name, you could use a variable substitution like `$(MAKE) -C $(subst _,' ',@)`.  But really, Just Don't Do That.

Comment: If the only time you need spaces in targets or prerequisites is during this subdirectory situation then you can do it; as Toby says there's no reason other than convenience that the phony directory targets have to have the same name as the actual directories.  But often these paths leak out into "normal" targets or prerequisites as well (header file paths, etc.) and that is not going to work, easily.  Avoid if at all possible.  You'll be happier for it.